# Python how to catch custom exception from boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am launching EC2 spot instances in Python using boto3.  I want to handle the error when the requested price is too low, but it's not working.  Using VS Code debugger, I can see the custom exception raised with `ClientError` class.  So I tried to catch it like this:

```
except ClientError as e:
  print(e.response)
```

This throws another exception:
**Exception has occurred: NameError**  name 'ClientError' is not defined

It's defined in `botocore.exceptions` which I believe is imported automatically by boto3.  I even tried importing botocore explicitly but that didn't help.

I can catch the exception generically with `except Exception as e`, but how can I catch this specific type of exception?

[image]

Comment: `from botocore.exceptions import ClientError`?

Comment: Thank you!  This works, but it doesn't feel like the right way to go.  So I have to import all the different exceptions separately?  I thought it would be automatic since I have imported boto3

Comment: You have to bring them into scope somehow, and [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). There may be some root boto exception you can use in cases where you're trying to catch several at once, you'd have to look at the source.

Comment: Another option, I can `import botocore` and then `except botocore.exceptions.ClientError`

Comment: Yes, there are a few equivalent options, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: You might be able to just `import botocore.exceptions`